# How to change certain text in all files using bash?

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I have a few directories, all of which have it's own index.html file inside. I want to scan these directories (I don't know how much of them will it be and how named) and replace one line in all of the index.html files they contain.

The line I look for is `base href="`. I want to put a given text at the end of this string. For example the text may be: `/testing/demo`. Then I want all the index.html files to contain `base href="/testing/demo`.

Also, two additional steps must be made - if there's a slash `/` at the end of the given string, it should delete it. If there's not a slash at the beginning, it should add it.

I tried to use `sed` comand somehow.

Comment: can you add a full example how its look like and how you expect it ?

Comment: It doesn't exist yet, I want to add it to my deploy script. I thought about something like: ```for d in $(find ${S3_URI} -type d); do find $d -iname "index.html"  .............```

Comment: And then use the ```sed``` command to replace the strings.

Comment: wrt `It doesn't exist yet` - we're asking you to create and post an example. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton when ask 'how to write something' how can I provide an example of it? I was just looking for some solutions. In the comment above I wrote how I wanted to approach the problem.

Comment: @HubertKubiak you want a tool to read input X and produce output Y. You must have SOME idea of what X and Y look like. All we're saying is create an example of X and the associated Y. Again, see [ask] and pay particular attention to the part about creating a [mcve]. Look at other questions on this site that have multiple upvotes for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to find all index.html files and add string after `base href="`:

> Dont forget to add `-i` as an option to `sed` to make it modify in place

The `-E` for extend regex usage as described in here:

> -E, -r, --regexp-extended
>                    use extended regular expressions in the script
>                    (for portability use POSIX -E).

We start by looking for each `index.html` file regardless the case sensitivity. and then we use `sed` to find `base href=` and capture it inside a group then we pass it to the second part of the sed command as `\1` after that we add the string we want to append.

For the second part of the question we can consider removing any `/` at the start of our string and also remove any `/` at the end and save the result in a variable which will be passed to `sed`

```
PARSED_URL=$(echo '/testing/demo/' | grep -oP '[^/].*[^/$]') ; find /path/you/want/to/lookup/ -iname "index.html" -exec sed -E "s~(base\shref=\")~\1/$PARSED_URL~g" {} \;
```

Input 1:

```
/testing/demo/
```

Input 2:

```
testing/demo/
```

Input 3:

```
/testing/demo
```

Input 4:

```
testing/demo
```

Output (after appending it to `base href="`)

```
base href="/testing/demo
```

Comment: What does -E flag mean here?

Comment: answer updated. if there is any other modification needed let me now so i can keep the answer updated

Comment: It's a very nice anwser but lacks one aspect of my question: ```if there's a slash / at the end of the given string, it should delete it. If there's not a slash at the beginning, it should add it.```

Comment: It's working fine, I get the updated index.html file in the console, but the file is not saved with the new content. How could I achieve this last step? :)

Comment: This is because you need to add `-i` to sed command, I just did not want to add it so you can check the result first

Comment: just make it `sed -i -E`

Comment: @HubertKubiak I have also added a answer to the previous question if you want to take a look at it